# Troubleshooting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-503

Need help in troubleshooting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503

A web application deployed on JBoss EAP 6.3 (client Application) creates an HttpURLConnection to another application deployed on GlassFish server (server application). There is firewall placed in between these 2 servers. The client application suddenly starts throwing java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for all the requests after successfully running for almost a day or two.

1.) As per GlassFish server admin, no further requests are coming to the server for processing. Though, I have asked for HTTP Access logs but not sure if 503 responses is logged by GlassFish in access logs.
2.) The firewall logs suggest no blocked traffic between these two servers.
3.) Network admin suggests wireshark is not able capture any outbound traffic which gives an 503 response.

My query is:

A connection.disconnect() method is being used for each created connection and connections are being created very frequently. Few links suggests that disconnect() method doesn't let the same TCP socket to be re-used by other requests and in this case, a new socket would be created every time. So it's better to close the InputStream instead. Can a failure in dynamic port allocation by underlying Windows operating system be resulted into a HTTP Response 503?

```
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);


        if (connection.getResponseCode()!= 200) {
            serviceStatus = code;
            serviceMsg = "Error occurred while getting data";
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String outStr = "";
        while ((outStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("OutS " + outStr);
            sessionKey += outStr;
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        serviceStatus = -1;
        serviceMsg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sessionKey;
}
```

Comment: ideally, you should have `connection.disconnect();` in finally block.

Comment: Please add stacktrace too

Comment: You are calling `setDoOutput(true)` but not doing any output. So remove it. It changes the request method to `PUT`, and you don't want that. You should not call `disconnect()` unless you know exactly why you are doing so, but you can't get a 503 unless you had a connection to get it over, and you can't get a connection in a state of exhausted ports. You need to look at the server logs to see why the 503.

Comment: @dkb Ideally you should not have it at all unless you know exactly why.